# Lsyncd options issue

Tags: shell, lua

I am trying to use the software called [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) and it uses a configuration file written in lua to store the configuration options.

```
settings = {
logfile = "/logs/log.log",
pidfile = "/var/run/lsyncd.pid",
statusFile="/var/log/lsyncd.stat",
statusIntervall=5,
delay = 1
}
sync {
default.rsync,
source = "/source/folder",
target = "/destination/folder",
excludeFrom="/etc/exclude",
}
```

The manual talks about the ability to run commands on action there is even an example

```
fgroup = "staff"

-----
-- script for all changes.
--
command = 
-- checks if the group is the one enforced and sets them if not 
'[[
perm=`stat -c %A ^sourcePathname`
if test `stat -c %G ^sourcePathname` != ]]..fgroup..'[[; then
        /bin/chgrp ]]..fgroup..'[[ ^sourcePathname || /bin/true; 
fi 
]] ..

-- checks if the group permissions are rw and sets them 
'[[
if test `expr match $perm "....rw"` = 0; then 
        /bin/chmod g+rw ^sourcePathname || /bin/true; 
fi 
]] ..

-- and forces the executable bit for directories.
'[[
if test -d ^sourcePathname; then
        if test `expr match $perm "......x"` -eq 0; then 
                /bin/chmod g+x ^^sourcePathname || /bin/true;
        fi 
fi 
]]

-- on startup recursively sets all group ownerships
-- all group permissions are set to 'rw'
-- and to executable flag for directories
--
-- the hash in the first line is important, otherwise due to the starting
-- slash, Lsyncd would think it is a call to the binary /bin/chgrp only
-- and would optimize the shell call away.
-- 
startup = 
'[[#
/bin/chgrp -R ]]..fgroup..'[[ ^source || /bin/true &&
/bin/chmod -R g+rw ^source || /bin/true &&
/usr/bin/find ^source -type d | xargs chmod g+x 
]]

     gforce = {
        maxProcesses = 99,
        delay        = 1,
        onStartup    = startup,
        onAttrib     = command,
        onCreate     = command,
        onModify     = command,
        -- does nothing on moves, they won't change permissions
        onMove       = true,
   }

   sync{gforce, source="/path/to/share"}
```

but I just want to execute a simple local command onCreate, onModify, onMove

```
 /path/to/script.sh args
```

I know is probably simple but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Commands seem to be strings. Then I would try:

```lua
...
onStartup = "/path/to/script.sh args",
onAttrib  = [[/path/to/script.sh args]],  -- both '', "", and [[ ]] are string delimiters
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
my_cmds =
[[
    /path/to/script.sh args
]]

monitor =
{
    delay    = 1,
    onAttrib = my_cmds,
    onCreate = my_cmds,
    onModify = my_cmds,
    onMove   = my_cmds,
}

sync
{
    monitor,
    source = "/source/folder",
    target = "/destination/folder",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the python script software [Watcher](http://github.com/greggoryhz/Watcher), and configure the jobs.yml as the example.

```
......
events: ['create', 'modify', 'move']
......
command:/path/to/script.sh args
```